# query is not notworking

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am using `mongodb` as my `database` and using `scala` for developing and i am new to this.
Now i have a problem in updating the database using a query

```
collectionProfile.update(BSONDocument("handle"->handle,"active"->true), BSONDocument("$set"->BSONDocument("messages.received"->BSONDocument("isRead"->true))))
```

and here is my collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5877969d1300005801327fa8"),
    "handle" : "sd3423dwwrewer342",
    "active" : true,
    "messages" : {
        "received" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "u-bf130421-418b-41a5-8965-0e7691b9412a",
                "by" : "S_0ECB8108_7771_4701_9813_D7D360B994AC",
                "to" : "J_04ABD48A_28D2_44CD_9D05_76C709E50724",
                "subject" : "hi",
                "content" : "hello",
                "time" : "2017-01-12T20:16:25.268",
                "isRead" : false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

here i am trying to update the isRead variable true but it is not working can anyone help me with this query.